# How to save the image(uploaded from Dropbox Chooser) to the folder?

Tags: javascript, php, dropbox-api

I know you think this as a silly question. But I am not able to get it done. I am using dropbox chooser to upload the images form user's dropbox account. Once they upload it, I am able to save it in the database, but I am not able to save it in the uploads folder. Following is my code:

**Index.php**

```
<form class="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div id="dropbox-container"></div>
    <input id="dropbox_image" name="image" type="hidden" />
    <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="wgiv8kvzvq57mlw"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    options = {
        success: function(files) {
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                add_img_to_list(file);
                document.getElementById('dropbox_image').value = file['name'];
            });
        },
        cancel: function() {
          //optional
        },
        linkType: "preview", // "preview" or "direct"
        multiselect: true, // true or false
        extensions: ['.png', '.jpg'],

    };

    var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
    document.getElementById("dropbox-container").appendChild(button);

    function add_img_to_list(file) {
        var li  = document.createElement('li');
        var a   = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = file.link;
        var img = new Image();
        var src = file.thumbnailLink;
        img.src = src;
        img.className = "th"
        document.getElementById("img_list").appendChild(li).appendChild(a).appendChild(img);
    }
</script>
```

**hController.php**

```
<?php
    $fileName = $_POST['image'];
    $tmpName = $_POST['image'];

    $image = new \Model\Upload_Picture();
    $image->image = $_POST['image'];            
    $fileName = uniqid()."_".basename($fileName);
    $fileName = str_replace(' ', '_', $fileName);
    $fileName = str_replace('-', '_', $fileName);

    move_uploaded_file(tmpName, UPLOAD_PATH . 'pictures/'. $fileName );

    $image->save();
?>
```

This code helps me to save the image into the database, but not storing it in the upload folder. I think I am making a mistake in some piece of code, help will be appreciated. Also if I upload multiple images from the dropbox account, I am not able to store all of them in my database. Only the last one is stored in db.

Comment: What step exactly isn't working as expected? The Chooser gives you a link to the selected file(s), and you can do whatever you want with that link. If you want to save the actual file data, you should set `linkType` to `"direct"`, and then make an HTTPS GET request to the returned link to get the file data,

Comment: @Greg I think Dropbox api is working fine for me, I am able to get the files and also able to store the image in databse. But I am not able to store it in my uploads folder. So I think its a PHP thing that needs to be check